# Shape mismatch with vgg16 keras: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2, shape received [None, None]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net, siamese-network

In trying to learn keras and deep learning, I want to create an image matting algorithm that uses an architecture similar to a modified autoencoder, where it takes two image inputs (a source image and a user-generated trimap) and produces one image output (the alpha values of the image foreground). The encoder part (of both inputs) is simple feature extraction using pre-trained VGG16. I want to train the decoder using the low-res alphamatting.com dataset.

Running the attached code produces an error:
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, None]`

I'm having trouble understanding this error. I verified that my twin_gen closure is producing image batches of shape (22, 256,256,3) for both inputs, so I would guess that the issue is that I have somehow created the model wrong, but I don't see where the error is. Can anyone help shed some light on how I could be seeing this error?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


def DeConvBlock(input, num_output):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_output, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_output, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_output, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return x


img_input = Input((256, 256, 3))
img_vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
img_vgg16._name = 'img_vgg16'
img_vgg16.trainable = False


tm_input = Input((256, 256, 3))
tm_vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
tm_vgg16._name = 'tm_vgg16'
tm_vgg16.trainable = False

img_vgg16 = img_vgg16(img_input)
tm_vgg16 = tm_vgg16(tm_input)
x = Concatenate()([img_vgg16, tm_vgg16])
x = DeConvBlock(x, 512)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 256)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 128)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 64)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 32)
x = Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)


m = Model(inputs=[img_input, tm_input], outputs=x)
m.summary()
m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

gen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, rotation_range=30, height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True, validation_split=0.2, preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
SEED = 49


def twin_gen(generator, subset):
    gen_img = generator.flow_from_directory('./data', classes=['input_training_lowres'], seed=SEED, shuffle=False, subset=subset, color_mode='rgb')
    gen_map = generator.flow_from_directory('./data/trimap_training_lowres', classes=['Trimap1'], seed=SEED, shuffle=False, subset=subset, color_mode='rgb')
    gen_truth = generator.flow_from_directory('./data', classes=['gt_training_lowres'], seed=SEED, shuffle=False, subset=subset, color_mode='rgb')

    while True:
        img = gen_img.__next__()
        tm = gen_map.__next__()
        gt = gen_truth.__next__()
        yield [[img, tm], gt]


train_gen = twin_gen(gen, 'training')
val_gen = twin_gen(gen, 'validation')


checkpoint_filepath = 'checkpoint'
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='auto',
    save_freq='epoch',
    save_best_only=True)


r = m.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=10, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you didn't specify the input shape of `VGG16` and you set `include_top=False`, so the default input shape will be `(None, None ,3)` for `channels_last` case.

PS: You can check the source code of `keras.applications.VGG16` and `keras.applications.imagenet_utils.obtain_input_shape` for detail.

As you can see the output `None` shape by calling `model.summary()`:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
img_vgg16 (Functional)          (None, None, None, 5 14714688    input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tm_vgg16 (Functional)           (None, None, None, 5 14714688    input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 8, 8, 1024)   0           img_vgg16[0][0]                  
                                                                 tm_vgg16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

To fix this you can simply set `input_shape=(256, 256, 3)` in `VGG16`, and calling `model.summary()` will now give you:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
img_vgg16 (Functional)          (None, 8, 8, 512)    14714688    input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tm_vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 8, 8, 512)    14714688    input_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 8, 8, 1024)   0           img_vgg16[0][0]
                                                                 tm_vgg16[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The main cause of the error is when you calling `__next__()` it return tuple of two array `(data, label)` with shape `((batch_size, 256, 256, 3), (batch_size, 1))`, but we really just want first one.

Also the data generator should yield `tuple` not `list` otherwise there will be no gradients provided for any variable, because the `fit` function expect `(inputs, targets)` as returning of data generator.

And you have another problem that your model's output shape is `(batch_size, 256, 256, 1)` but your `gen_truth` elements shape is `(batch_size, 256, 256, 3)` when you load the `gen_truth` image with `color_mode='rgb'`, in order to get same shape with model's output you should load `gen_truth` using `color_mode='grayscale'` if you have grayscale image or load it using `color_mode='rgba'` and get the last channel value if you want using alpha value (I just guess it from the description in your question, but you should get the idea)

Example code that running without any problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

def DeConvBlock(input, num_output):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_output, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_output, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_output, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return x

img_input = Input((256, 256, 3))
img_vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), weights='imagenet')
img_vgg16._name = 'img_vgg16'
img_vgg16.trainable = False

tm_input = Input((256, 256, 3))
tm_vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), weights='imagenet')
tm_vgg16._name = 'tm_vgg16'
tm_vgg16.trainable = False

img_vgg16 = img_vgg16(img_input)
tm_vgg16 = tm_vgg16(tm_input)
x = Concatenate()([img_vgg16, tm_vgg16])
x = DeConvBlock(x, 512)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 256)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 128)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 64)
x = DeConvBlock(x, 32)
x = Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

m = Model(inputs=[img_input, tm_input], outputs=x)
m.summary()
m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

gen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, rotation_range=30, height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True, validation_split=0.2, preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
SEED = 49

def twin_gen(generator, subset):
    gen_img = generator.flow_from_directory('./data', classes=['input_training_lowres'], seed=SEED, shuffle=False, subset=subset, color_mode='rgb')
    gen_map = generator.flow_from_directory('./data/trimap_training_lowres', classes=['Trimap1'], seed=SEED, shuffle=False, subset=subset, color_mode='rgb')
    gen_truth = generator.flow_from_directory('./data', classes=['gt_training_lowres'], seed=SEED, shuffle=False, subset=subset, color_mode='grayscale')

    while True:
        img = gen_img.__next__()[0]
        tm = gen_map.__next__()[0]
        gt = gen_truth.__next__()[0]
        yield ([img, tm], gt)

train_gen = twin_gen(gen, 'training')

r = m.fit(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Hmmm, you are right that adding the input_shape makes the model summary look more correct, but unfortunately I still get the same error. Do I need to set the input_tensor or anything like that?

Comment: Then there also have problem within your data generator, I'll update the answer

Comment: @ike I update the answer, check if you have another problem

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe this fixes the issues. I am seeing CUDA errors now but I think that is a completely separate issue and I'll try to figure that out on my own. Thanks again, accepting your answer now.

Comment: The cuda errors were solvable on my end, so I have verified that your answers here were correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @ike Glad to help : )

Comment: can you help in this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225332/invalid-argument-in0-mismatch-in1-shape